# iOS Safari (iPhone SE) auto complete not working HTML5 autocomplete attributes added

Tags: html, ios, autocomplete

We have a web form, and using the tips from [iOS Safari Autofill / autocomplete sections not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138814/ios-safari-autofill-autocomplete-sections-not-working) however the current iOS doesn't work on the codepen here: https://codepen.io/grigs/pen/YqoyWv

Is there any definitive way to get auto complete to work on iOS Safari?

And example input field is:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="font-weight-bold input-label" for="FirstName">First name * <span class="field-validation-valid field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input input-about-you" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter your first name(s)" autocomplete="given-name" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="">
</div>
```

Every other browser respects the HTML5 autocomplete hints, except iOS Safari it seems - so would be great to get it working.

The exact phone we're struggling with is and iPhone SE MX9R2B/A - so an iPhone SE 2020. I'm sure it may affect other iOS with Safari.

Answer (score 4):

The codepen example seems correct, I just tested on
`iPhone SE 2nd generation - iOS14.4` Emulator

[SE2020 - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU3py.png)

The trick you might be missing is enabling `AutoFill` on Safari mobile to do this go to: `Settings > AutoFill > toggle Use contact info/Credit Cards`(if desired)

You might also refeer to this guide [Safari’s strange behavior](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/#safaris-strange-behavior) it's from 2016 but there explains a lot of the autofill behaviour.